# How to modify files in Jboss deployment war file?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, war

I'm used to deploy application war files on Tomcat and now need to work on Jboss-EAP with realy tight deadline so don't have much time to learn.
I saw that the main difference is that the war file is not being extracted when I'm starting the jboss instances like it did in Tomcat.
Jboss is just deploying what's in the war file.
So how do I modify files in the war file?
Do I need to extract, change and repackage for every change?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the deployment scanner and the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments folder to copy your exploded war file there. Another solution is to explode you deployed war using th jboss-cli and upload files to it to replace them: https://www.wildfly.org/news/2017/09/08/Exploded-deployments/

Comment: Interesting! @ehsavoie thank you for this information.